SQL Developer: select value if column does not exist
Please I am trying to select the sales unit price for all months in customer order, and I want to return '0' if the month does not exist in the database :
This is my database :

The selected result shows only existed months :

I want to show something like this :

Do you have any idea please? Thank you.

You can create CTE with all 12 months and then LEFT JOIN it to your table.

Use a row-generator to generate a set of all the months and then OUTER JOIN to your table and use COALESCE to set the sales_price to 0 when there was no matching row:
SELECT m.month_name,
       COALESCE(col.sales_price, 0) AS sales_price
FROM   ( SELECT LEVEL AS month,
                TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1970-01-01', LEVEL - 1), 'MON') AS month_name
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
       ) m
       LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_order_line col
       ON col.month1 = m.month
ORDER BY m.month

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE customer_order_line (month1, sales_price) AS
SELECT 10, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8,   82 FROM DUAL

Outputs:



MONTH_NAME
SALES_PRICE




JAN
0


FEB
0


MAR
0


APR
0


MAY
0


JUN
0


JUL
0


AUG
82


SEP
0


OCT
1000


NOV
0


DEC
0



fiddle

One option is to use recursive cte for months generation. The cte's resultset should be Left Joined to your table to get your expected result...
--    S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table customer_order_line ( MONTHS1, SALES_PRICE ) AS
Select 10, 1000 From Dual Union All
Select  4,   82 From Dual

--      S Q L :
SELECT    To_Char(m.MMM, 'Mon') "MONTHS3", Nvl(c.SALES_PRICE, 0) "SALES_PRICE"
FROM    ( WITH  mnths (RN, MMM) AS    -- Recursive cte named mnths
            (  Select 1, To_Date( '2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) From Dual 
             UNION ALL
                Select RN + 1, To_Date( '2024-' || Lpad(To_Char(RN + 1), 2, '0') || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) 
                From mnths m Where RN <= 11
            )  Select * From mnths  
        ) m    -- m here is an alias of cte's resultset
LEFT JOIN  customer_order_line c ON( c.MONTHS1 = m.RN ) 
ORDER BY   m.RN

/*    R e s u l t :
MONTHS3      SALES_PRICE
------------ -----------
Jan                    0
Feb                    0
Mar                    0
Apr                   82
May                    0
Jun                    0
Jul                    0
Aug                    0
Sep                    0
Oct                 1000
Nov                    0
Dec                    0    */

See the fiddle here.
